# Do not understand the text in health check

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-network-load-balancer

I am looking at the following [page](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#multiple-probers) where it says:

```
Sum over backend services. If a backend is used by multiple backend services, the backend instances are contacted as frequently as the sum of frequencies for each backend service's health check.
```

Now I don't quite understand what the following means:

```
...the backend instances are contacted as frequently as the sum of frequencies for each backend service's health check.
```

Can someone please help me break this down.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**... the sum of frequencies for each backend service's health check.** refers to the sum of the Check interval `check-interval` configuration flag for each service defined. The default for each is `5s`

---

**What is a backend service?**

A `backend service` defines how `Cloud Load Balancing` distributes traffic. The backend service configuration contains a set of values, such as the protocol used to connect to backends, various distribution and session settings, health checks, and timeout

---

What is `check-interval` config flag?

From [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#probes)

> The check interval is the amount of time from the start of one probe issued by one prober to the start of the next probe issued by the same prober. Units are seconds.

Comment: Thank you @Tushar. Can the text then be refactored as follows just for clarity: <br/>
> If a backend is used by multiple backend services, the backend instances are contacted as frequently as the sum of frequencies for each backend service's health check. The frequency of a backend service’s health check refers to the `check-interval` configuration flag on the backend service. The default value is 5 seconds.

Comment: Also, can you point me to the API documentation for `check-interval`. I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Nosail yes thats correct and I have the link on my answer (click Docs) - https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#probes

Comment: Thanks Tushar. Yes, I did check that out and refactored the text based off that. Thank you for your time. :)